# Machine learning algorithms for suggesting new baby names

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, machine-learning-model, algorithms, ai

https://www.lexalytics.com/lexablog/machine-learning-natural-language-processing

https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-meeting-industrys-requirement-by-applying-state-of-the-art-deep-698d2b3b4ede

https://medium.com/mysuperai/what-is-named-entity-recognition-ner-and-how-can-i-use-it-2b68cf6f545d

https://blog.skyl.ai/understanding-deep-learning-algorithms-for-ner

https://www.bounty.com/pregnancy-and-birth/baby-names/baby-name-search

Can Machine learning algorithms assist in suggesting new Baby names?

Separate input dataset for all the male and female existing names.

Separate input dataset for male and female gender names.

Entity Category : Person First Name.

Note : Every Person Name has a meaning.

Thanks & Regards,

Prashant S Akerkar

Comment: Machine learning can help but in a rather trivial way, other solutions like random selection or random recombination are way better IMO

Comment: For such a broad and general question, I'd suggest to start with a Google search. It will return plenty of results for name generation incl. baby names. If you end up having a specific question this site might be more suitable.